# Obtaining equivalent of Brewfile as backup without using "brew"

Tags: terminal, backup, homebrew, recovery

My MacBook is broken but I can boot into recovery mode. I have multiple local users on this machine, each having a local instance of homebrew with their own configured taps, casks, mas applications, etc.

I am trying to create a Brewfile for each of the local users, with an output similar to what `brew bundle dump` provides (with taps, casks etc), so that I can easily reinstall everything later on. However, I cannot use the `brew` binary to generate this information. This is because I cannot run brew as root user in recovery mode.

Can this information be retrieved differently? Is there a database anywhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things? Are these local users all on one machine, and is this the same machine that's currently in recovery mode? If yes to both then we can assume you have a broken machine in some way and are attempting a recovery? You might be best to open your question with that info, a slight restructuring of the question. Dare I ask if you have a backup?

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy. Correct, yes to both questions. I have a Time Machine backup but it's not the latest state. And yes, this seems to point to the right direction, although it doesn't fully answer my question, which I will try to rephrase.

Comment: I am not familiar with the structure of homebrew to be fair, but I don't think the link provides all the information I need. This would give me a list of all kegs - do you know where I can find the equivalent for casks (Caskroom directory?), mas applications, taps?

Comment: `root` can `su` (switch user) to any user on your system. I not a brew user so, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks, in recovery mode only root is accessible afaik, so not able to switch with su.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The first link in the answer on the original question gives you all the details you need. Both the Cellar and the Caskroom directory are within the Homebrew directory of the respective user. So a simple `ls` to a file should be enough. You probably can also just tar/gzip each Homebrew directory and copy it to the new machine.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, the terminology link helped answer my question. Sorry I hadn't looked at it properly, only the answer itself.